# How do you file for a patent, like how do you prepare a draft for the patent, in Canada?

Tags: filing, drafting, patalent

I wanted to file for a patent in Canada. I don't know how to proceed with that like prepare a draft or something.

Comment: Whole books are devoted to answering that question. This site works better with specific questions that have specific answers. I'll give this bit of advise, hire a patent lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

Drafting patents is a deep and subtle field with unwritten rules that can change overnight due to a court decision. There are books and expensive classes but talking to an authorized practitioner is likely to be more cost-effective in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a Lawyer, specializing in Intellectual Property Rights (IPR), then I suggest you **hire a Patent Attorney** or a Canadian lawyer specializing in IPR. Reason is because there is monetary cost, huge cost, involved in filing a patent.

You may want to draft the patent application on your own. However, the application might get rejected even for the smallest wording. Remember, there is cost associated with a patent application, both monetary cost and time. Know that there is lot of research work, etc. involved before you draft your patent application. The nature and amount of information you need to enter into the patent application varies from industry to industry. Scientific patents need plenty of information, including drawings and images.

Alternatively, you might want to check out for Paralegals or Lawyers on Upwork and such platforms who provide drafting services. They will provide a draft (time + you pay them for the work). Ensure that such a person is well acquainted with Canada's IP laws and has the appropriate legal qualifications. Then, take the draft to a local Patent Attorney (cost and time involved) who might accept or reject it based on completeness + correctness + accuracy, etc.

So, save yourself your time and your valuable money.

You might want to check this URL:
https://www.canada.ca/en/services/business/ip/patents.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer and welcome to Ask Patents.

Comment: It is likely that a para-legal would not be licensed to actually provide legal advice or independently draft legal documents, including patent applications. The filing fees are much,  much lower than attorney fees and putting in a lot of "legal" work to try to save attorney time is not likely to help - it is very rare that anything drafted by an inventor, other than a clear description if the invention, is usable. And welcome to Ask Patents.

Comment: @george-white  Paralegals may not have a Bachelor or higher degree of Law. However, they need to complete Paralegal studies and take a qualifying exam before they can take up paralegal work to assist a Lawyer or Attorney. Usually, paralegals research and/or draft legal content.

Comment: At the direction and supervision of an attorney.